# LINQ to Entities chaining commands with differing results

Tags: c#, linq

My question is more general, but I have an example to help illustrate:

```
db.aTable.Where(x => x.Date < someDateInThePast).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First()
```

That gives me one item, which differs from the item returned by this command:

```
db.aTable.Where(x => x.Date < someDateInThePast).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First()
```

(note the "ToList()" in the middle).

From what I can see, what is actually happening in the 1st example is the OrderBy is completely disregarding the filtering that is done by the .Where(). It is ordering the entire `aTable`.
And the 2nd query is giving the actually correct item.

The `.Date` parameter is a DateTime type (on SQL side it is a 'datetime').

Is this behaviour to be expected from LINQ to Entities?

Comment: May be you have several items with same max `Date` and ordering on database and client side selects different the one result from them. You can add additional ordering like: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Id)` to ensure same results.

Comment: My actual LINQ contains an additional section in the .Where() which filter by an ID, and each ID has maximum 1 entry per date. I have checked anyway, and for the 1st query I get an item with date of 27/11/2017. While the 2nd one gives the correct most recent one of 15/03/2018. It almost looks like it is doing the ordering on raw characters (eg 27 > 15) but I can't prove it

Comment: This is a weird question, its not really even a question as its impossible to reproduce your results to answer. You need to create a minimal example, a table description with minimal columns and type definitions and some sample data that reproduces your problem. also you will need to tell us what DB you are using. as it stands its impossible to know what you are seeing or why

Comment: Adding the ToList() should not make any difference to the O/P , But as TheGeneral said , you need expand the code with i/p for others to cross verify once

Comment: what is sql query get generated by you first approach , can you please checkt hat

Comment: @PranayRana I can see that the SQL being generated doesn't contain an 'Order By' statement. Do you know if that should be appearing in the SQL? Or it's done client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fully explain why it works like this but I have found that the inclusion of the `First()` is what is causing the issue. When I view the raw SQL that is generated by the LINQ there is no reference to 'Order By' in it. I can only assume the ordering happens on the client side. But, there is reference to take 'TOP (1)' in the SQL. Meaning, because the SQL server is only returning 1 result, the order by is happening on just 1 result and doesn't do anything useful.

If I change `First()` to `ToList()` then the ordering works as expected. This doesn't solve my issue but it explains the behaviour.

Comment: The second query `db.aTable.Where(x => x.Date < someDateInThePast).ToList()` won't ever translate into a `TOP (1)` query. Did you show the exact code that caused the issue?

Comment: You're correct: the 2nd query doesn't have `TOP 1`. Only the 1st query does. That's part of the reason why the 2nd query works.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `.ToList()` you actually change the context in which the data is processed.

Your first query is handled by your database completely and you only return the value from `.First()` to your Entity-Instance.

In the second one, you basically give the command to load up the conditioned `aTable` by giving him the command `.ToList()` and THEN order it, add the second condition and pick the first `Date` value from that already instanced table.

Microsoft states [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#store-execution) that a CLR change might lead to unexpected results, which is what you are doing.

One way to know exactly what is happening would be that you execute your statement on your SQL Server directly:

```
Select Top(1) Date
From aTable
Where Date < someDateInThePast
order by Date desc
```

And then create a dbset for your data up to the point where the context changes:

```
Select * 
From aTable
Where Date < someDateInThePast
order by Date desc
```

And then call it separately in your c# environment. Then check whether the results still differ.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, but still that shouldn't make a difference for the end result.

Comment: Yes it does. You force the query to behave according to the client's CLR, except for the DB's.

Comment: Source: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#store-execution)

Comment: No. The `datetime` datatypes are 100% compatible and (as far as I know) handled equally. I did know that CLR changes might cause unexpected results, but I'm not 100% sure what exactly is causing this. 
I personally don't think that the `Date` attribute is the culprit. I think the context change messes something up in the statement.

Comment: One of the comments above mentioned looking at the SQL that's being generated. I noticed that there is no 'Order By' statement included in the SQL. Not sure if it is meant to be in there or not.

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to. There is an `order by` statement with each of the code-blocks

Comment: I'm referring to my own code/application. When it executes and I look at the SQL that is being generated, there is no 'Order By' in it.

Comment: You do have an `OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)` in both of your statements.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I'm saying that the raw SQL that is generated from my LINQ code does not contain it. ie: the command that is actually being sent from my app to the SQL server doesn't contain the Order By.